# Erroneous intentions in vows

Tags: halacha, mistakes, nedarim-shevuot, intent-accident-purposely

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (Ganzfried) [67:6](http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur67.html) states:

> "A vow does not take effect unless one's words and one's heart agree. However, if one made a vow by mistake, not intending to say what one did say, or thought about making a vow, but did not say it out aloud, this is not a vow."

I am looking for more information about error of intention when someone pronounces a vow. What is the source, and what are the implications, of this ruling in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch, and is it generally accepted as normative Halacha?

Comment: far22, please [register](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features, including the ability to log back in to your account so you can edit and comment on your own posts.

Comment: See Shulchan Aruch Yoreh De'ah 210:1 - http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&pgnum=14. This is the source for the Kitzur.

Comment: Thank yo! Do you have it in english or french? Also, do you know if there is sources in nedarim or shevuot?

Answer (score 1):

It seems he is basing himself on Shulchan Aruch [YD 210:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6597) based on Bavli [Shevuot 26b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=26&daf=26b&format=pdf).

Answer (score 0):

My Rav in New York,  NY recently gave a quick shiur on this subject directly out of Masekhet Nedarim (because of the coinciding of Parashat Matot, which discusses the same subject in the first 'Aliyah). He presented the exact same conclusion that the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch states here. I will ask my Rav for the exact source used.

Comment: Thank you veru much! Do you think I should also read the parasha?